# How to make slider size smaller on home-page using Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, header

I have a an issue of making the header image on our homepage (https://meltrac.com.au) smaller. I still want it to fill the whole page, but I would like to edit the height.

Someone who can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you have a question regarding a commercial product as WordPress, you should ask it on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). If it is regarding your code, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the height of the image is controlled dynamically by the carousel plugin using Javascript. Also, the photo appears to be both an `<img>` element and a background image. The former is being displayed below 768px of screen width.

You could try using CSS to limit the height of the carousel. In the example below I've made it 66% of the viewport height. I've also centred the background image and added some margin-bottom when the `<img>` element is displayed so that it isn't hard against the content below.

This would be added to your theme's Custom CSS input, if it has one.

```
//Limit the carousel height
.home .home-banner .owl-item.active > .item,
.home .home-banner .owl-item.active,
.home .home-banner .owl-stage, .home .home-banner .owl-stage-outer,
.home .home-banner .owl-carousel {
    max-height: 66vh;
}

//Center the background image
.home .home-banner .owl-item.active > .item {
    background-position: center !important;
}

//Add some white-space on smaller screens
.home .home-banner .owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```